# Want to create new object, instead project duplicates

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I have a problem with my project. I want my class Baustein to be a blueprint of an object I can place in my Display in the gui_backup.py. The program launches and everything works, but as I click the left button (button1) the same program opens again and now I have 2 programs going separately but I have no new Object in the Display created, just the old one which is being created in gui_backup in blue, but I want to create one in red with the class Baustein from Bauklotz_class.py. Here are my codes:

Bauklotz_class.py

```
from gui_backup import Display
class Baustein:
    x1, y1, x2, y2 = 10,10,20,20
    color = "red"
    def __init__(self, x1, y1, x2, y2, color):
        self.x1 = x1
        self.x2 = x2
        self.y1 = y1
        self.y2 = y2
        self.color = color
    def show_new_object(self):
        quadrat2 = Display.create_rectangle(40, 50, 60, 70, fill = color)
        Display.coords(quadrat2, 40, 50, 60, 70)
```

gui_backup.py

```
from tkinter import *
import curses

x1 = 10   #initialise coordinates
y1 = 10
x2 = 20
y2 = 20

root = Tk() #create window
root.wm_title("Raspberry Pi GUI") #window title
root.config(background = "#FFFFFF") #background color

#The whole left frame and widgets involved
leftFrame = Frame(root, width=200, height = 400)
leftFrame.grid(row=0, column = 0, padx = 10, pady = 3)
leftLabel1 = Label(leftFrame, text = "Platzhalter Text")
leftLabel1.grid(row = 0, column = 0, padx = 10, pady = 3)
leftLabel2 = Label(leftFrame, text = "Dies ist ein Text\nmit mehreren Zeilen")
leftLabel2.grid(row = 1, column = 0, padx = 10, pady = 3)


#the whole right frame and widgets involved
rightFrame = Frame(root, width=400, height = 400)
rightFrame.grid(row = 0, column = 1, padx = 10, pady = 3)
E1 = Entry(rightFrame, width = 50)
E1.grid(row = 0, column = 0, padx = 10, pady = 60)

#The two functions for the 2 buttons created
def callback1():
    import Bauklotz_class
    test = Bauklotz_class.Baustein(20, 30, 40, 50, "red")
    test.show_new_object()

def callback2():
    print(1+1)

buttonFrame = Frame(rightFrame)
buttonFrame.grid(row = 1, column = 0, padx = 10, pady = 60)
B1 = Button(buttonFrame, text = "Button1", bg = "#FF0000", width = 15, command = callback1)
B1.grid(row = 0, column = 0, padx = 10, pady = 60)
B2 = Button(buttonFrame, text = "Button2", bg ="#FFFF00", width = 15, command = callback2)
B2.grid(row = 0, column = 1, padx = 10, pady = 60)

Slider = Scale(rightFrame, from_ = 0, to = 100, resolution = 0.1, orient = HORIZONTAL, length = 400)
Slider.grid(row = 2, column = 0, padx = 10, pady = 3)

Display = Canvas(rightFrame, width = 300, height = 300)
Display.configure(background = 'black')
Display.grid(row = 1, column = 3, padx = 10, pady = 3)

quadrat = Display.create_rectangle(20, 30, 40, 50, fill = "blue")
Display.coords(quadrat, x1, y1, x2, y2)


#following functions are for coordination of the square
#also you can find here the exceptions so that the object
#cant break out of the display widget

def down(event):
    global x1, y1, x2, y2
    if x2 == 290 or y2 == 300:
        pass
    else:
        y1 += 10
        y2 += 10
        Display.coords(quadrat, x1, y1, x2, y2)
        leftLabel1.config(text = "x1: " + str(x1) + ", x2:" + str(x2) + ", y1:" + str(y1) + ", y2:" + str(y2), width = "40" , )
def up(event):
    global x1, y1, x2, y2
    if x2 == 0 or y2 == 10:
        pass
    else:
        y1 -= 10
        y2 -= 10
        Display.coords(quadrat, x1, y1, x2, y2)
        leftLabel1.config(text = "x1: " + str(x1) + ", x2:" + str(x2) + ", y1:" + str(y1) + ", y2:" + str(y2), width = "40" , )
def left(event):
    global x1, y1, x2, y2
    if x1 == 0 or y1 == 10:
        pass
    else:
        x1 -= 10
        x2 -= 10
        Display.coords(quadrat, x1, y1, x2, y2)
        leftLabel1.config(text = "x1: " + str(x1) + ", x2:" + str(x2) + ", y1:" + str(y1) + ", y2:" + str(y2), width = "40" , )
def right(event):
    global x1, y1, x2, y2
    if x1 == 290 or y1 == 300:
        pass
    else:
        x1 += 10
        x2 += 10
        Display.coords(quadrat, x1, y1, x2, y2)
        leftLabel1.config(text = "x1: " + str(x1) + ", x2:" + str(x2) + ", y1:" + str(y1) + ", y2:" + str(y2), width = "40" , )    
root.bind('<a>', left)
root.bind('<w>', up)
root.bind('<s>', down)
root.bind('<d>', right)


root.mainloop()
```

Here are also some screenshots for you to understand it better:

[image: Screenshot before pushing left button]

[image: Screenshot after pressing left button]

Does someone know why my project is duplicating itself?

Comment: does importing `Bauklotz_class` at the top of gui-backup.py instead of inside `callback1` change anything?

Comment: Yes, I checked it now. The 2 windows spawn instantly. I dont need to press any button, there will instantly be 2 windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies within your double import, i guess. You see, you import from gui_backup.py into Bauklotz_class.py, while also importing vice versa, which leads to weird and unexpected behaviour. Also, inside the definition of `show_new_object`, you should use `self.color` instead of `color` as an argument for `Display.create_rectangle`, because `self.color` is a class attribute and thus the proper object to use in a class method definition. One way to fix your Problem is to add an additional attribute, let's call it `canvas`, to `Baustein`, and removing the `import Display`, so Bauklotz_class.py now looks like this:

```
class Baustein():
    x1, y1, x2, y2 = 10, 10, 20, 20
    color = "red"

    def __init__(self, x1, y1, x2, y2, color, canvas):
        self.x1 = x1
        self.x2 = x2
        self.y1 = y1
        self.y2 = y2
        self.color = color
        self.canvas=canvas

    def show_new_object(self):
        quadrat2 = self.canvas.create_rectangle(40, 50, 60, 70, fill=self.color)
        self.canvas.coords(quadrat2, 40, 50, 60, 70)
```

And then call it like this in gui_backup.py:

```
...
def callback1():
    import Bauklotz_class
    test = Bauklotz_class.Baustein(20, 30, 40, 50, "red", Display)
    test.show_new_object()
```

which will fix your problem, and create a red rectangle instead of duplicating your window.